# field 'day' missing in date table in Lua - plantweb optics

Tags: lua

#### Summary of issue

Facing `field 'day' missing in date table` issue while adding days to timestamp extracted as an object.

#### my try

I have converted object to string and then adding the days to the timestamp, no use.

```
local my_obj = syslib.getobject(myPath)
local my_ts = tostring(my_obj)

local y, m, d, Hr, Min, Sec, Milli = my_ts:match '(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+) (%d+):(%d+):(%d+).(%d+)'
local new_ts = os.time({ year = y, month = m, day = d, hour = Hr, min = Min, sec = Sec }) + 1*24*60*60
local next_time = string.format("%s.%03d", os.date("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", new_ts), Milli)
syslib.setvalue(my_obj, next_time)
```

Please help

Comment: provide your input string. looks like `d` is nil.

Comment: `os.time{}` throws the exact same error. This means your match is failing and all of `y, m, d, Hr, Min, Sec, Milli` are `nil`. Please do what Piglet said. Your pattern should escape the dot as millsecond separator: `%.`.